# Trying Ubuntu Forever

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion Notebook, but it had a Low-graphics mode error, which meant I couldn't use it forever.

So, then I started my machine using Try Ubuntu, and it works like charm.

I am asking, if there is a way that I can use it forever, without ever having to install Ubuntu.

The reason I ask is because when I try to install something using the terminal, it gives me a lot of dependency errors.

How to resolve this? Any of the problems? I want to get Ubuntu running on my laptop.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 1.1.12-2~oneiric1) but 1.1.12-2~oneiric1 is to be installed
     Depends: libaa1 (>= 1.4p5) but 1.4p5-38build1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.3ubuntu0.11.10.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.3ubuntu0.11.10.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.4-2ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.1-9ubuntu3 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but 1.2.10-2.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.10-1) but 1.2.14-6.1ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.1-9ubuntu3 is to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.0.12~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.12~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-randr0 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
```

Comment: What graphics card/chip does your computer have (`lspci`), also could you add one of these dependency errors to your question, please?

Comment: I have a RAEDON 8500 HD graphics card. But when I use lspci, it doesnt get listed there. It only shows the default Intel 3rd Generation. And, I will list that in a moment.

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/617664/edit) button below your question to add information.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 11.10? Or why does it try to install oneiric packages? And do you **really want to** keep using the live system? I assume you fell into the [X-Y-Problem trap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: 'apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade' might help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Could you tell me why does the Try Ubuntu feature works like charm on my laptop, with no graphic bug, but gives the error after I install it on an external hdd?

Comment: Do you get the The folowing packages have unmet dependencies error on the Try Ubuntu (and is this what you are seeking to fix)? Also, what is the output of `lspci -v` in Try Ubuntu, and in the installed Ubuntu? The issue may be that a updated driver in the installed version does not work. Installing a newer version of Ubuntu that is supported like 14.04 would likely work best.

Comment: 14.04 works. 